# Sorting a Table with Vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js

If I ever want to sort a table with Vue.js, should I always get the data to be sorted received in an ajax request ? for the v-repeat to work? or which would be the way to make it with data coming from a controller?

I wanna know if this is the only way to proceed when using Vue.js
Im trying to use an already fetched table in the traditional way and then sort its header fields eg. (title, created_at)

```
 @foreach($sliders as $slider)
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>{{$slider->nombre}}</td>
                  <td>{{$slider->mensaje}}</td>
                  <td>{!!Html::image($slider->thumb_path)!!}</td>
                  <td>{{$slider->publicado}}</td>
                  <td>{{$slider->created_at}}</td>
                   <td>{!!link_to('admin/slider/'.$slider->id.'/edit', 'editar','class="btn btn-primary"')!!}
                      {!!link_to('admin/slider/'.$slider->id, 'borrar','class="btn btn-danger"')!!}
                  </td>
 @endforeach
```

I want my table to be like 
http://javascriptbook.com/code/c12/sort-table.html
but with Vue.Js and with Data received from a controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `orderBy` Vue filter, for example:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th v-repeat="column: columns">
        <a href="#" v-on="click: sortBy(column)">{{ column }}</a>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr v-repeat="users | orderBy sortKey reverse">
      <td>{{ name }}</td>
      <td>{{ age }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and

```
data: {
  sortKey: 'name',

  reverse: false,

  columns: ['name', 'age'],

  users: [
    { name: 'John', age: 50 },
    { name: 'Jane', age: 22 }
    // ...
  ]
},

methods: {
  sortBy: function(sortKey) {
    this.reverse = (this.sortKey == sortKey) ? ! this.reverse : false;

    this.sortKey = sortKey;
  }
}
```

[[demo]](http://codepen.io/pespantelis/pen/ojwgPB)

Comment: hello @pespantelis, the answer you propose involves the v-repeat directive but if I have to use that approach I would have to fetch my data with an Ajax request right?? and then populate the view using v-repeat . But what about if my data was already  called to the view and all I want to make is use Vue.js to Sort the given table, please check to this thread. https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/sorting-a-table-with-vue

Comment: Btw, I will proly accept your answer, if there is no way to Sort the table like a non asynchronous way, i would like to use but Im new to Vue.js the v-el. As I know, Vue.js is a Translator between View and Javascript like Jquery,  it makes your life easier when making js code right?

Comment: I will give your answer as valid because I couldn't find the answer I need, so as I see Vue.js works as you and in the laracasts tutorials explain. Thanks.

Comment: @Pantelis Peslis - How to make this work with Vue 2.*